# Vignette mask effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect where the background image shows at the borders with a white vignette in the center of the page behind the content. The solution I have now is problematic cross-browser. Perhaps I'm missing some css, or I'd be open to a different approach: [www.hvactapes.com](http://www.hvactapes.com)

```
<body>
    <div id="vignette-wrapper">
        <div id="vignette-blur"></div>
    </div>
</body>



body {
    background-image: url(/background-md.jpg);
    position: relative;
}

#vignette-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

#vignette-blur {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.98);
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    min-height: 1024px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(43px);
    filter: blur(43px);
    margin: 200px auto 0;
}
```

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this with css3 box-shadow on your wrapper:after.

Here is a simple tutorial explaining how create this effect: http://nimbupani.com/vignettes-with-css3-box-shadows.html

box-shadow should work cross-browser in pretty much all modern browsers(except for opera-mini).

hope this helps. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) which [has great browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

### Example

```css
body {
    background-image: url('http://www.beaconsinn.com/images/media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lkpvcrUmPJ1qhk2te.jpg');
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body:before {
display: block;
position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
content: '';
background: radial-gradient(
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 100), 
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 100),
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
);
}

#vignette-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}


#vignette-blur {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(red, yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="vignette-wrapper">
        <div id="vignette-blur"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```